# Redux adding nested value to current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following state:

```
{
  list: {
    key1: {
      value: [{a: 'a'}, {b: 'b'}],
      fetching: true
    },
    key2: {
      value: [{c: 'c'}],
      fetching: true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to provide a new value for some key, and replace current state with this. But I also want the value to be concated with the previous one. So for example with the following action:

```
key1: {
  value: [{d: 'd'}],
  fetching: false
}
```

I would get the following state:

```
{
  list: {
    key1: {
      value: [{a: 'a'}, {b: 'b'}, {d: 'd'}],
      fetching: false
    },
    key2: {
      value: [{c: 'c'}],
      fetching: true
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do that inside a reducer, so that the case remains immutable? (using `...` spread operator, not `ImmutableJS`).

EDIT:

Part of the reducer that handles (should to) that:

```
case "FOO_BAR":
  const key = action.payload.key;
  const newList = {...state.list};
  newList[key] = action.payload.newObject; // {value: ..., fetching: ...}
  return {
    ...state,
    list: newList
  }
```

Comment: Post up your current reducer.

Comment: Sure, I just did. It does only replacing part right now.

Comment: Do you care about duplicates in your value arrays?

Comment: Yup, it should only add what I passed to the end of my value array.

Answer (score 0):

It's how I'd like to solve it

```
case "FOO_BAR":
  const oldList = {...state.list};
  const newKey1Value = action.payload.key.value;
  oldList.key1.value = oldList.key1.value.concat(newKey1Value);
  const newKey1fetching  = action.payload.key.fetching;
  oldList.key1.fetching =  newKey1fetching;
  return {
    ...state,
    list: oldList
  }
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: @user99999  I hope it works for you, but I always do it in my action and pass the corrected object to the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the spread operator to spread the old values and then spread the newObject[key] value array.

Something like this:

```
import { get } from 'lodash';

case "FOO_BAR":
  const { key, newObject } = action.payload;
  const newList = {
    ...state.list, 
    [key]: {
      value: [...get(state, 'list[key].value', []), ...newObject[key].value]
      fetching: newObject[key].fetching
    }
  };
  return {
    ...state,
    list: newList
  }
```

Edit: I added [the `get` utility function from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) so that if `state.list[key]` is `undefined`, it will return an empty array to spread rather than throwing an error.